# Any free C# libraries for video recording (of the screen) around?

Tags: c#, .net, video-capture, video-recording

I am looking for free C#(.net) libraries that allow me to record videos(plus sound) of the screen of my computer (basically, to do what camtasia does).

Is there anything easy to use, around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this solution to your problem, which uses Windows Media Encoder 9 to record the desktop. It's a bit dated, but I think you might find it interesting or helpful: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/EnhancedDesktopRecorder07222008041309AM/EnhancedDesktopRecorder.aspx