# Recording/sending screen stream C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, video-streaming, screenshot

I am looking for a C#.net library to help me record the stream of one PC's screen and then send the recording live to another application through a socket.

I found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529024/any-free-c-sharp-libraries-for-video-recording-of-the-screen-around) regarding the screen capturing, but this library can only broadcast to a certain port, I want to be able to send the recording live to another application through socket, so if anyone have any other class or something to add to this to make it able to send the live broadcast to the other computer that would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4_Overview.aspx), which includes API access for just about everything you can do through the UI.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee Not a lot on-line, but IIRC the SDK comes with a bunch of samples that were enough for me to get a workable encoder going.

Comment: can you please tell me what is IIRC?